# Finding left-sided limit with square root

Tags: calculus, limits

Finding $$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\sqrt{9}+\sqrt{-x}.$$

I am having trouble solving this limit, I am not sure if you plug in $0$, or if you plug in a number close to zero approaching from the left side and get undefined. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Exactly. The **real**  function $\;\sqrt{-x}\;$ is defined only on the non-positive reals and thus the limit when $\;x\to 0\;$ cannot exist. At most only the left sided limit has some meaning.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}{\left( \sqrt{9} + \sqrt{-x} \right)}$, or something else? Notice that if x is approaching 0 from the left (and so taking only negative values), then -x is approaching 0 from the right (i.e. is taking only positive values).

Comment: You are right that you should plug in a number close to zero on the left.  You are wrong that the result is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to plug in zero numerically, because in your limit you accounted for the fact that you are approaching zero from the left hand side.
So this answer is just plain 3.
Also notice that the point (0,3) is not an open dot. It is a point of the curve.
Zero is in the domain of the function and 3 in the range.